# CSS '+ p' positioning for speech bubble

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

I've used a couple of different sources to devise a hybrid CSS speech bubble setup but am having difficulty with the positioning of a title under each bubble (see screenshot below for how it looks and the changes I'd like to make).

[image]

I used [this](http://forrst.com/posts/How_to_Make_a_Pure_CSS_Speech_Bubble_With_a_Drop-PU1) as my inspiration for the bubble itself and [this](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/) as my inspiration for having the title appear underneath the bubble - and herewith a big thank you to Joshua Hibbert and Nicolas Gallagher for their respective work.

The `.bubble + p` CSS looks very compact but I can't get it to work properly with my setup. I've tried changing the `position` attribute from `relative` to `absolute` and back again but neither works as hoped. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/M9TZv/) (drag the Fiddle's Result slider to the left to see the bubbles displayed as intended). Can anyone please indicate what I can do? And am I right in presuming that the `+ p` in the CSS means that the `<p>` element inherits its CSS from the bubble element?

**HTML**

```
  <span class="bubble bubble-left">This is line 1 in speech bubble 1.<br/> 
    This is line 2 in a bubble,<br/> and this is line 3.</span>
    <p>Title for bubble 1</p>

  <span class="bubble bubble-right">This is ine 1 in a speech bubble 2.<br/> 
    This is line 2 in a bubble,<br/> and this is line 3.</span>
    <p>Title for bubble 2</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.bubble {
background-color: #fff;
-webkit-border-radius:7px;
-moz-border-radius:7px;
border-radius: 7px;
border: 2px solid #DD4814;
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)); 
-o-filter: drop-shadow(4px 4px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.5), 4px 4px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.2);
color: #333;
display: inline-block;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
font: 16px/25px;
padding: 15px 25px;
position: absolute;
}

.bubble + p {margin:15px 0 2em 85px; font-style:italic;}

.bubble:after, .bubble:before {
border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid #fff;
bottom: -25px;
content: '';
position: absolute;
right: 25px;
}
.bubble:before {
border-right: 25px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,.1);
bottom: -28px;
right: 22px;
z-index: 1;
}
.bubble:before {
border-right: 27px solid #DD4814;
border-bottom: 27px solid transparent;
bottom: -29px;
right: 23px;
z-index: 0;
}

.bubble-left {left: 25%;}
.bubble-right {right: 25%;}
```

Comment: "And am I right in presuming that the `+ p` in the CSS means that the `<p>` element inherits its CSS from the bubble element?" No; it just means that the `<p>` element comes directly after `.bubble` in your markup as a sibling (which it does given the code in your question), and inheritance does not exist between siblings.

Answer (score 1):

I would have the speech bubble span inside your `<p>` then the code would look like so:

HTML:

```
<p>
    Title for bubble 1
    <span class="bubble bubble-left">
        This is line 1 in speech bubble 1.<br/> 
        This is line 2 in a bubble,<br/> 
        and this is line 3.
    </span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    position: relative;
}

span.bubble {
    position: absolute;
    /* Set width and height in relation to the p */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dsundy, unfortunately (likely given my inadequate CSS experience) I cannot get it to work as required.